# Cannot Get More Than Basic User Info with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, spfx

Having followed the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aad-tutorial#DeploymentAndPermissionsGrant, my SharePoint web part experiences an error when I try to retrieve anything more than the basic fields.

For example, *this* call works:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,mail,userPrincipalName

However, *this* call results in a `501 Not Implemented` exception` stating, **"This operation target is not yet supported."**

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,mail,userPrincipalName,hireDate

In my package-solution.json:

```
"webApiPermissionRequests": [
  {
    "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
    "scope": "User.Read.All"
  }
]
```

The calling script is very simple i.e.:

```
this.context.msGraphClientFactory
  .getClient()
  .then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {
    // From https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript sample
    client
      .api("users")
      .version("v1.0")
      .select("displayName,mail,userPrincipalName,hireDate")
```

I have already approved the access via the `/_layouts/15/online/AdminHome.aspx#/webApiPermissionManagement` page:

[image]

**Update:** I also tried updating my "[package-solution.json to use the value Microsoft.Azure.AgregatorService rather than Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aad-tutorial#deploy-the-solution-and-grant-permissions)" but when attempting to approve the permission on the API management page (screenshot above), I get this error:

> [HTTP]:400 - [CorrelationId]:5134e69e-f000-8000-b901-2a4b8bab60b8 [Version]:16.0.0.8929 - A service principal with the name Microsoft.Azure.AgregatorService could not be found.
>    Parameter name: resourceName

I am also not seeing the permissions I've approved under SharePoint Online Client Extensibility - Permissions in the Azure Portal (not sure if I am supposed to, but I just wanted to mention it!).

[image]

This is my `request-id` if it helps someone from Microsoft figure out what might be going on!

> ed3ff30c-d552-462e-be70-c69a19275049

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has responded to my support ticket stating that when returning multiple users, it is not possible to retrieve certain fields i.e. birthday and hiredate. When requesting an individual user, the fields will be available in the response.

Comment: The docs are pretty poor I've discovered that MS provide for MSGraph.